# Does the vierbein contain any extra information?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

The vierbein from General relativity has $D(D+1)/2$ independent components when accounting for the $O(3,1)$ gauge symmetry.
The metric has the same degrees of freedom. But does the *vierbein* contain any extra information that you can't get from the metric? Or if you are given a metric can you construct the vierbein up to gauge symmetry?

As an example $x$ and $x^2$ have the same degrees of freedom. But $x$ has one piece of additional information that is whether a number is positive or negative.

Comment: As discussed in Deser and Isham's "Canonical vierbein form of general relativity" ([eprint](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/85931/1/PhysRevD.14.2505.pdf)), it appears the "extra information" amounts to extra gauge symmetries.

Answer (score 4):

The existence of a globally defined [vielbein](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vielbein) means that the spacetime manifold $M$ is a [spin manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure), i.e. the first & second [Stiefel-Whitney (SW) class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class) vanish, which is not necessarily true for a generic [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$. E.g. the vanishing of the first SW class means that the manifold is [orientable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability).

Comment: I see. So the vierbein tells you that the manifold is orientable. To know a sphere is orientable you can paint one side of it. So in that regards defining a vierbein must be akin to knowing which side of the sphere you are on. Not sure how that works in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Qmechanic, does the Einstein's Equivalence Principle (i.e metric is locally Minkowski) already implies that any "physical" spacetime should be a spin manifold?  And does a generic non-spin manifold cannot satisfy the EEP?  How can a non-spin manifold have any physical sense if we can't locally diagonalise the metric at any point, using some functions $e_{\mu}^a(x)$ in any coordinates system?

Comment: But this does not mean that the vielbein carries more information, right? A Pseudo-Riemanninan manifold either is or is not a spin-manifold, right?

Comment: $\uparrow$ I agree.

Comment: @Cham: Concerning Einstein's [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), note that [Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) & [Fermi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates) normal coordinates exist for any pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.

Comment: @Qmechanic, I don't see how a pseudo-riemann manifold can be a non-spin manifold.  Can't we always define a tetrad from the functions $e_{\mu}^a(x)$ that diagonalise (locally) the metric?

Comment: Locally yes, but we might not be able to extend it smoothly globally.

Comment: @Qmechanic, you mean that the functions $e_{\mu}^a(x)$ could be discontinuous or even singular at some points of coordinates $x$, while the coordinates themselves are regular at that point?  Physically, that would be odd, and even unacceptable.  That would be the same as saying that the metric itself is discontinuous or singular at that point.